# Need a alternate approch to do SQL to LINQ conversion

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to get a particular result set for my View to bind. I'm new to Linq expression, so I'm not very sure about the different ways of doing it.

Here is my `MenuModel`

```
public class MenuModel : DisposeBase
    {
        public string ParentID { get; set; }
        public string ParentName { get; set; }
        public List<MenuItemModel> MenuItems { get; set; }
    }
```

My `MenuItemModel`

```
public class MenuItemModel : DisposeBase
    {
        public string ChildID { get; set; }
        public string ChildName { get; set; }
        public string PageURL { get; set; }
    }
```

`MenuModel` is the output type I'm expecting as a result set. I'm getting result set of type `DataTable` from backend

```
DataTable dtable = oDatabase.ExecuteAdapter(System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SP_GETUSERNAVMENUDATA");
```

Here is my SQL result set,

[My DataTable will looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFyIW.png)

Now I need to convert this Datatable to type `MenuModel`.

I tried to Query distinct `MenuModel` and based on that I'm building `MenuItemModel` object.

```
List<MenuModel> lstMenuModel = dtable.DataTableToList<MenuModel>()
                                            .GroupBy(p => new { p.ParentID, p.ParentName })
                                            .Select(g => g.First())
                                            .ToList<MenuModel>();

            foreach (MenuModel parentItem in lstMenuModel)
            {
                List<MenuItemModel> lstUserMenuItemData = dtable.DataTableToList<MenuItemModel>()
                                                .Select(i => new { i.ChildID, i.ChildName, i.PageURL, i.ParentID })
                                                .Where(i => i.ParentID.Equals(parentItem.ParentID))
                                                .ToList<MenuItemModel>();
            }
```

But still I'm getting conversion error while building `MenuItemModel`. Now I wanted to know, is there any best practice to do this same conversion of these nested class type? I'm sure there should be something simple to do so.

Any help could be appreciated. Thanks!

Note: DataTableToList is a method that will convert DataTable object to specific generic type

Comment: What do values in PARENTID and CHILDID mean?

Comment: What is `DataTableToList()`? And in order to generate the model you need, that method would need to project into a model with all 5 properties

Comment: PARENTID is the ID of Parent menu and CHILDID is the ID of child menu inside particular parent menu. @MarkoJuvančič

Comment: I have updated my Question, please find the NOTE at end of my question. If I create a class with all 5 properties then I might end up duplicate the properties. A single Parent can have multiple Child objects. I wanted to maintain the model relation in same way which I mentioned. @StephenMuecke

Comment: @KarthickJayaraman, You must initially project into a model with all 5 properties and them do the grouping on that (or use `.AsEnumerable()` on the `DataTable` and reference the column names which is a bit ugly) - you will not end up with duplicates

Comment: @StephenMuecke If I do so, will I get my result in MenuModel object type? I badly needs my output of MenuModel  type. Can you give me some example?

Comment: @StephenMuecke As you said, I created one more class MenuSQLSet that holds all 5 properties. Now, I can able to get my required result set based on the Linq which you shared as response. Thanks a lot. I'm marking your response as Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not clear what your `DataTableToList<MenuModel>()` method is doing or returning, but it would need to return a collection of a model that contains all 5 properties represented in the data table.

Assuming you have the following model

```
public class MenuSQLSet
{
    public string ParentID { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public string ChildID { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    public string PageURL { get; set; }
}
```

then your query should be

```
List<MenuModel> lstMenuModel = dtable.DataTableToList<MenuSQLSet>()
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.ParentID, x.ParentName })
    .Select(x => new MenuModel()
    {
        ParentID = x.Key.ParentID,
        ParentName = x.Key.ParentName,
        MenuItems = x.Select(y => new MenuItemModel()
        {
            ChildID = y.ChildID,
            ChildName = y.ChildName,
            PageURL = y.PageURL
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Alternatively you can use `.AsEnumerable()` on the `DataTable` and reference the column names

```
List<MenuModel> lstMenuModel = dtable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => new { ParentID = x["ParentID"], ParentName = x["ParentName"] })
    .Select(x => new MenuModel()
    {
        ParentID = x.Key.ParentID,
        ParentName = x.Key.ParentName,
        MenuItems = x.Select(y => new MenuItemModel()
        {
            ChildID = y["ChildID"],
            ....
```

Comment: As a side note, why in the world would you convert the data returned by your SP to a DataTable, then convert the DataTable to a model. This is the 2nd MVC question I've see this year that still uses DataTables - I thought you were all extinct :) - You should just use a `DataReader` and read directly into a collection of your model.